# The class instantiating its own via a static method

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Is it better to have a class creating its own instance via a static method or preferable via a constructor like I am doing with a parameter less constructor.
The usage from other classes now appear to be a bit weird if using the static method like

```
RegenerateId()
{
 Id = ClientId.NewClientId();
}

    public class ClientId: Identity<Guid>
    {
        public ClientId(Guid value) : base(value)
        {
        }
    
        public ClientId() : base(Guid.NewGuid())
        {
        }
    
        public static ClientId NewClientId(Guid id)
        {
            return new Client(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'Better' in what way? I'm afraid your question in its current form will only attract opinion-based answers and is doomed to be closed soon. Try to add some scope to the question by at least adding some overall goal to accomplish using either of the two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you should prefer regular constructors. Since using `new` is the most common and natural way to create objects. In your given example I see no specific reason to have a static factory method.

In some cases it is useful to be able to create an object in different ways using the same type of parameter. For example `Angle.FromDegree(45d)` and `Angle.FromRadian(Math.Pi / 4)`. If this is the case it might be useful to make the constructor private to ensure no one writes `new Angle(45)` and makes a mistake. Or if you have multiple parameter less ways to create your object that you need to differentiate, say `ClientId.NewZeroId()` and `ClientId.NewRandomId()`.

In some cases, it can be useful to have a separate non-generic static class to help with type inference. I.e. `Tuple.Create(42, "42")` instead of `new Tuple<int, string>(42, "42")`